# Move cursor to end of EditText?

Tags: android

I'm replacing some text in an EditText, then I want to move the cursor to the end of the current text input. It kind of seems to work - when I start typing again, the cursor seems to be at the end of the EditText, but it doesn't flash / blink anymore. I have to touch the EditText again for the cursor to start blinking again. Am I doing it wrong?:

```
editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length()-1);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 51, accepted):

One trick I used was setting the text to "" and then appending the entire string I wanted.

i.e.

```
String newtext = editText.getText().toString() + "the new text";
editText.setText("");
editText.append(newtext);
```

This seems to place the cursor in the right place for me.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reset all the test because I have spans I need to maintain. Does the cursor appear to be blinking for you again after you do the above, though?

Answer (score 23):

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inbox);
et.setSelection(et.getText().length());
```

**second approach**

There is a function called append for ediitext which appends the string value to current edittext value and places the cursor at the end of the value. You can have the string value as the current ediitext value itself and call append();

```
myedittext.append("current_this_edittext_string");
```

Comment: imo the first approach is neat

Answer (score 1):

> **For letting the user change the whole text within the Edit Text** (making more user friendly)

```
editText.selectAll(); //user can delete the whole text at one go
editText.requestFocus();
```